# WPF MVVM combobox only displays the smallest number of items after updating properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am currently facing an issue with a combobox displaying only 1 items instead of all the items in the combobox.

So what I have is a listbox listing out all the parent items. Additionally there is one selected item that will be called SelectedParent.
ex : Parent1
     Parent2
     Parent3

Each parent has their own number of child, and selecting a Parent item will automatically update the combobox to contain the correct child items. So let's say Parent 1 has Child 1, Child 2 and Child 3  while Parent 2 only has Child 4. Selecting Parent 1 and clicking the combobox will display all three child (correct behaviour)

```
Parent 1      --- -  Child 1
              -----  Child 2
              ------ Child 3
```

Now selecting Parent 2, will also display the correct child which is Child 4

```
Parent 2      --- -  Child 4
```

However switching back to Parent 1, the combobox now will only display one item when clicked, which is the first item Child 1

```
Parent 1      --- -  Child 1
```

Child 2 and Child 3 is hidden from the combobox, even though debugging the code I found that that the Property Contains both Child 2 and Child 3. I have tested various combinations and basically the combobox dropdown will only display the smallest number of elements, when switching between parents.

The pseudocode is written below and I am using MVVM pattern.

```
ListBox x:Name="Item" Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  
                 ItemsSource="{Binding AllParentItems}" 
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParent}" >

<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChild}" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding AllChildItems}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name">
```

I am using MVVM pattern, and in the viewmodel's properties, I define the following properties:

```
public ObservableCollection<T> AllParentItems
{
    get{...} // populate and retrieve the Parent values 
}

public T SelectedParent

    {
        get {return _selectedParent;}
        set {
             _selectedParent = value;
             GetChildrenForThisParent();
    }}

private GetChildrenForThisParent()
{
     // based on the state of the selected parent,
     // it will set AllChildItems differently
     // for example it will return list containing Child1, Child2, or Child 3
     // and for the different parent, ALlChildItems will have only Child 4
}

public Observable<T2> AllChildItems
{get;private set;}
```

I have tried the MaxDropDownHeight and other properties of Combobox but no change was observed. Would any of you know of such issue or any possible solutions? Thank you very much for your assistance !

Comment: it looks like either a binding issue or something slightly wrong that you can debug, I  would suggest you to change binding mode to item source to two way and see if that changes anything... good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements would be easier to implement if you used a hierarchical data structure. By that I mean that if you had a parent data class that contained a collection of child items, you could data bind to the child items of each parent directly like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Item" Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllParentItems}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParent}" ... >

<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChild}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllParentItems/ChildItems}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" ... >
```

Note the `AllParentItems/ChildItems Binding.Path`, which means *the `ChildItems` property of the selected item from the `AllParentItems` collection*. See the [`Binding.Path` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for more information about `Binding Path`s.